# How add values in a two dimensional array in Android

Tags: android, arrays, multidimensional-array

I created an multidimensional array for making a list of all assigned ids of task with its subtasks.

```
//VARIABLES
    int rowIndex = 2;
    int colIndex = 1;
    int rowIndex2 = 2;
    int colIndex2 = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
private String[][] ListAllIds;
```

and then when the user clicked the "**ADD NEW TASK**" button,

```
public void addTask(View view) {

        i++;
        Map<String, Integer> idsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String tname = "task" + Integer.toString(i);
        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        param.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        param.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(rowIndex);
        param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(colIndex);
        editText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        editText.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text);
        editText.setText(tname);
        editText.setLayoutParams(param);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams param2 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        param2.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(rowIndex2);
        param2.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(colIndex2);
        textView.setPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

        textView.setLayoutParams(param2);

        if (rowIndex > 1) {
            textView.setText("TASK "+Integer.toString(i)+": ");
            editText.setId(i);
            idsMap.put(tname, i);
        }

        ListAllIds[i][j] = tname;
        gridLayout.addView(editText);
        gridLayout.addView(textView);
        rowIndex++;
        rowIndex2++;
        this.j = 0;
    }
```

It will error on this line -> ListAllIds[i][j] = tname;
I don't know why. **Is it the incorrect way to add values in an array?**

The function when the user clicked the "**Add new subtask**" button,

```
public void addSubtask(View view) {
        j++;
        Map<String, Integer> idsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String taskno = "task" + Integer.toString(i) + "subtask" + Integer.toString(j);
        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        param.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        param.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(rowIndex);
        param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(colIndex);
        editText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        editText.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text);
        editText.setText(taskno);
        editText.setLayoutParams(param);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams param2 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        param2.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(rowIndex2);
        param2.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(colIndex2);
        textView.setPadding(30,0,0,0);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        textView.setLayoutParams(param2);

        if (rowIndex > 1) {
            textView.setText("Subtask "+Integer.toString(j)+": ");
            editText.setId(j);
            idsMap.put(taskno, j);
        }

        //allEdittext.add(i-1,editText);

        ListAllIds[i][j] = taskno;

        gridLayout.addView(editText);
        gridLayout.addView(textView);
        rowIndex++;
        rowIndex2++;
    }
```

I only like to make a two dimensional array of the ids of tasks with their subtasks.

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

**ListAllIds[1][0]** = "task1";

**ListAllIds[1][1]** = "task1subtask1";

**ListAllIds[1][2]** = "task1subtask2";

**ListAllIds[2][0]** = "task2";

**ListAllIds[2][1]** = "task2subtask1";

**ListAllIds[3][0]** = "task3";

---

**TASK 1:** ________

Subtask 1: _____

Subtask 2: _____

**TASK 2:** ________

Subtask 1: _____

**TASK 3:** ________

I don't know the correct syntax on how to add values in a two dimensional array in android.

Comment: Arraylist has only one dimensional. I need two dimensional array. @RaviGadipudi

Comment: ArrayList<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(); use this and put your string array as a list object

Comment: @RaviGadipudi and how do i add values with that? I'm new in Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm also quite new to android and java, but from what i've understood :

Classic arrays (such as String[]) are initialised with a fixed number of object. Meaning you can modify objects in the array, but you can not add new objects to it.

If you don't know how many elements you'll be storing in your array, use ArrayList instead of the classic Arrays. This way you will be able to add new elements.

Here and example where i create a list, that contains some lists of Strings :

```
ArrayList<List<String>> myArray = new ArrayList<>();
myArray.add(Arrays.asList("task1", "subTask1", "subTask2"));
myArray.add(Arrays.asList("task2", "subTask1"));

// get the task1 value
String task1 = myArray.get(0).get(0);

// get the subTask1 of task2
String subTask1ofTask2 = myArray.get(1).get(1);
```

An another way to add elements to this ArrayList :

```
myArray.add(new ArrayList<String>());
int lastElementIndex = myArray.size()-1;
List<String> lastElement = myArray.get(lastElementIndex);
lastElement.add("task3");
lastElement.add("subTask1");
lastElement.add("subTask2");

// get the task3 value
String task3 = myArray.get(2).get(0);
```

Comment: i have two different functions - Add New Task and Add New Subtask - when i click "add new subtask", i can't connect it to the task array. It will go on a separate array.

Comment: i cant use that code cause i have two different functions - "ADD NEW TASK" and "ADD NEW SUBTASK". If i use that code on either those two functions, it end up like adding separate array list. like this -> myList.add(Arrays.asList("task1")); if i clicked "ADD NEW TASK" button.

Comment: and myList.add(Arrays.asList("task1subtask1")); if i clicked "ADD NEW SUBTASK" button.

Comment: it must be that they on the same Arraylist not separated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
ArrayList<String[]> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] test1 = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
    String[] test2 = new String[]{"d","e","f"};
    String[] test3 = new String[]{"g","h","i"};
    String[] test4 = new String[]{"j","k","l"};

    strings.add(test1);
    strings.add(test2);
    strings.add(test3);
    strings.add(test4);

    // to edit and save back
    String[] temp = strings.get(0);
    temp[1] = "z";
    strings.set(0, temp);
```

let me know if you have any questions

Comment: is there any way i could add values by putting which index to add. like this ListAllIds[1][0] = "task1"; ListAllIds[1][1] = "task1subtask1";

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize the `String[][]` when you declare the array like below

```
private String[][] ListAllIds=new String[row_count][column_count];
```

please refer this [link](http://java67.blogspot.in/2014/10/how-to-create-and-initialize-two-dimensional-array-java-example.html)

Comment: ListAllIds = new String[][]{};

Comment: try  this ListAllIds=new String[50][50];

Comment: it wont throw any exception because the row count and column count is defined.

Comment: you have to mention row_count and column_count when your initializing an array.

Comment: i dont want to limit the count

Comment: if you dont want to limit the count you have to use ArrayList<> or Hashset.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ArrayOfArrays

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> myList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

then fill it as :

```
myList.add(Arrays.asList("task1","Task1subtask1","Task1subtask2"));
myList.add(Arrays.asList("task2","Task2subtask1","Task2subtask2"));
```

Comment: i cant use that code cause i have two different functions - "ADD NEW TASK" and "ADD NEW SUBTASK". If i use that code on either those two functions, it end up like adding separate array list. like this -> myList.add(Arrays.asList("task1")); if i clicked "ADD NEW TASK" button.

Comment: except no, because `Arrays.asList` returns list that does not support adding new values

Comment: and myList.add(Arrays.asList("task1subtask1")); if i clicked "ADD NEW SUBTASK" button.